# PHP Background job not displaying results

Tags: php, background, jobs

I have done a lot of research on how to create jobs that run in the background using PHP.

```
 <?php
   ignore_user_abort(true); // run script in background 
   set_time_limit(0); // run script forever 

   // get the size of the output
   ob_start();
   include_once '';//many includes
   //$contentLength = ob_get_length();
   // these headers tell the browser to close the connection
   // once all content has been transmitted
   //header("Content-Length: $contentLength");
   header('Connection: close');
  // flush all output
  ob_end_flush();
  ob_flush();
  flush();

  // close current session
  if (session_id()) session_write_close();


 //lot of code, fetch query from DB with millions records and do calculations

  ?>
```

When I use header("Content-Length: $contentLength"); the script does not return anything. When I comment it I get results for some thousands using limit. If I want to retrieve all millions the server stops responding after just 3-4 minutes

I just need to get a huge statistics report and do not want to have the user get a message 
max time execution reached. I do not want to raise time execution limit, as the limit is unknown. It could take up to hour. I need it to run in the background.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to process the report in snippets, i.e 10000 lines at the time. Save each computed portion as a file, then combine all files before outputting. 
You'd need to call the processing/creating snippets functionality via Ajax. This way you create one user-experience, but several tasks on the server. You can then also display progress so the user knows what's going on and you can also check if it's fallen over.

Comment: Yes, this helps. Nice approach